# Invalid labels for classification logistic regression model in pyspark databricks

Tags: pyspark, logistic-regression, databricks, apache-spark-ml, multiclass-classification

I am using Spark ML library for classification problem using a logistic regression.

I have vectorized input features and created training dataset and test dataset.

While fitting the model I get invalid labels issue.

[image: invalid labels issue]

the training dataset is :

where my input features as `Independent_features` and my target feature as `Category_con`.

[image: training dataset]

Answer (score 0):

Use the words : label, features instead of independent_features and Category_con while creating your vectors.

Answer (score 0):

For the labels, you would need to change them into just 3 categories. It looks like you might have 6 from the error message. You would need to use conditional replacement to group or bin the categories like below:

`train_df.withColumn('label', when((col('Category_con') == firstCondition) ).otherwise(when((col('Category_con') == secondCondition) ).otherwise(lastCondition))`